# Area under Frequency response function (amplitude vs frequency)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, energy, frequency-response

Recently, I was plotting frequency responses of multi-degree spring-mass systems and I was wondering what does the area under the FRF (amplitude vs frequency) (or in general FFT) mean? Does it have any significance?

Comment: Have you had a look at the following post on the Signal Processing S.E.? [Interpreting the amplitude of signals in fourier transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62908/interpreting-the-amplitude-of-signals-in-fourier-transform)
If it should not be of any help, what are the specifics separating this question from yours?

Comment: Look up the $H_2$ norm, the integral of the frequency response is the $H_2$ norm of the system (if it's stable)